# struct initialization in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Before you mark it as a duplicate/downvote, **I have read books, spend decent amount of time on Internet researching this, but I CANNOT find an answer.**

I want to initialize my struct when I create it. But I also want to declare it as a type using typedef

Here is what I am trying to do

```
typedef struct Clock_TAG Clock;

struct Clock_TAG{
  int time;
}Clock = {
  0
};
```

And it gives me an error "redefinition of 'Clock' as different kind of symbol"

```
typedef struct Clock_TAG{
 int time;
}Clock = {
  0
};
```

Gives "illegal initializer (only variables can be initialized)"

I know I have to use the name of the struct in order to initialize it, I want to initialize it at the time of it's creation, so please do not suggest having an init() method.

This is an example code, **I want to specifically understand HOW I can have a typedef AND struct initialization in the .h file**
I know there are many ways around this, I can omit using typedef or initialize the struct members the other way, but I want to understand why this gives me an error and how to fix it.

P.S
Is it also legal to malloc the struct in .h file?

Comment: You did not read carefully or lack understanding how typedef and `struct` definitions and variable definitions work. The compiler already tells you exactly what is wrong. And you should never _define_ a variable in a header.

Comment: I did read very carefully and yes I lack understanding, that is the reason why I am asking. Well, another person in my previous question on stackoverflow told me this is the right way to do this.

Comment: @Olaf also do you mind explaining why?

Comment: This should be explained in the books you read. if not, read a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `typedef` is an alias, when stating:

```
typedef struct Clock_TAG Clock;
```

and stating after that typedef:

```
struct Clock_TAG{
  int time;
} Clock = {0};
  ^^^^^
```

You're trying to initialize a `struct` name. Probably what you meant was:

```
typedef struct Clock_TAG Clock;

struct Clock_TAG{
  int time;
} clock = {0};
```